# Python 'theory' - constructing a multifunction program - how to plan a basic flow

Tags: python, modularity

I've written a few little things in python, and I am ramping up to build something a little more challenging.

The last project I made basically ingested some text files, did some regex over each file and structured the data in an useful way so I could investigate some data I have.

I found it quite tough near the end to remember what section operated on what part of the text, especially as the code grew as I 'fixed' things along the way.

In my head, I imagine my code to be a series of small interconnected modules - descrete .py files that I can leave to one side knowing what they do, and how they interoperate.

The colleague that showed me how to def functions basically meant that I ended up with one really long piece of code that I found really hard to navigate and troubleshoot.

(1) Is this the right way? or is there an easier way of making modules that pass variables between them, I think i would find this better, as I could visualise the flow better (mainly becuase its how I was used to working in MATLAB a few years ago I guess)

(2) Can you use this method to plan out the various layers of functions before hand to give you a 'map' to write towards?

(3) is there any easy to access tutorials for this kind of stuff? I often find the tutorials suddenly jump way over my head....

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question belongs to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) check out their [faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Please find some other code examples.  Seriously.  Your colleague should not be the only source of code that you're reading.  Please find **any** open source project in Python.  Then read their code.  " find the tutorials suddenly jump way over my head".  Please be **specific** Which tutorial jumped way over your head?  What **specifically** did you find confusing about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) It is possible to write a fine programme in a single .py file

(2) In any style of programming, it is always (apart from special, hardware-driven cases) best to break your code up into short functions (or methods) that accomplish a discrete task.

(3) Experienced programmers will frequent write their code one way, discover a problem, either  write more code, or different code, and consider whether any of their existing code can be broken out into a separate function.

A sign that you need to do this is when you are sequentially assigning to variables to pass data down your function. Never copy-paste your code to another place, even with changes, unless it be to break it out as a function, and replace the original code with a call to that function.

(4) In many cases, it can be useful to organise your code into classes and objects, even when it is not technologically *necessary* to do so. It can help you see that you have defined a complete set of operations (or not) necessary on some collection of data.

(5) Programming is actually quite hard. Even among those who have a talent for it, it takes a while to be comfortable. As an illustration, when I was doing my master's degree, I and my (fairly talented) friends all felt only in our final year that we had begun to achieve a degree of facility and competence (and these are all people who had been programming since at least their teenage years).

**The important thing is to keep learning and improving, rather than repeating the same one or two years of experience over and over**.

(6) To that end, read books and articles. Try new things. Think.

Answer (score 3):

Others have suggested studying other experienced programmers' code from open source projects, etc. and from tutorials and textbooks, which is sound advice.  Sometimes a similar example is all you need to set you on the right path.

I also suggest to use your own frustration and experience as feedback to help yourself improve.  Whenever you find yourself thinking any of the following:

- It feels like I'm writing the same code over and over again with only small changes
- I wrote this code myself, but I had to study it for a long time to re-learn how it works
- Each time I go back and add something to this code it takes me longer to get it working again
- There's a bug in this code somewhere, but I haven't a clue where
- Surely somebody somewhere has solved this problem already
- Why is this taking me so long to get done?

That means you have room for improvement in your technique.  A lot of the difference between an expert and beginning programmer is the ability to do the following:

- Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY): Instead of copy-pasting code, or writing the same code over and over with variations, write a single common routine with one or more parameters that can do all of those things.  Then call that routine in multiple places.
- Keep It Simple (KIS): Break up your code into simple well-defined behaviors/routines that make sense on their own, organized into classes/modules/packages, so that each part of the overall program is easy to understand and maintain.  Write informative and concise comments, and document the calls even if you don't intend to publish them.
- Divide & Conquer Testing: Thoroughly test each individual class, function, etc. by itself (preferably with a unit-testing framework) as you develop it, rather than only testing the entire application.
- Don't Re-invent the Wheel: Use open source frameworks or other tools where possible to solve problems that are general and not specific to your application.  In all but the most trivial cases, there is a risk that you do not fully understand the problem and your home-grown solution may be lacking in an important way.
- Estimate Honestly: Study your own previous efforts to learn how long it takes you to do certain things.  Try to work faster next time, but don't assume you will.  Measure yourself and use your own experience to estimate future effort.  Set expectations and bargain with scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know even where to begin answering your question without a snippet of your code for reference.  You might want to post your code to a free public site such as http://www.bitbucket.org/ or http://www.github.org/ and then include some specific questions about small snippets of code with links back to your repository.  This allows respondents here to look at the code and comment on it. (Both of these options even include color syntax highlighting, and interested correspondent can even pull the code down, make changes and push up a patch or create their own branch of your code and send you a "pull" request so you can look at the differences and pull selected changesets back into your branch).

More generally there are a number of approaches to program design.  You seem to be trying to re-invent a very old methodology which is referred to as "functional decomposition" --- look at the overall task at hand as a function (digest text files) and consider how that breaks down (decomposes) into smaller functions (ingest input files, parse them, prepare results, output those) and then breaking those down further until you have units which are small enough to be coded easily in your programming environment (Python).

Modern approaches (and tools) tend to use object oriented design methodologies.  You might try reading: http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/oodesign/build-python/html/index.html